# basic trig: How to find angle of a parallelogram inside a box, when box dimensions and 1 dimension of parallelogram is known?

Tags: trigonometry

First-time poster.  [image]

Essentially, I am building an angled leg for a desk, and I need to know the angles and lengths for cutting.

I am using wood that is 9" wide, and with the help of software, I have built a construction model based on my project requirements.  There are two critical points of intersection between the box and the rectangle - the pivot on the bottom left of the box (as seen correctly in the photo) and the top right corner of the box (NOT DISPLAYED CORRECTLY IN THE PHOTO.  I have not yet figured out how to merge line:point in fusion 360 while maintaining the 9" parallel relationship of my workpiece).  These are my known variables.

Unknown variables:  Once the rectangle is cut to fit in the box, I will have a parallelogram.  How do I find the angles of the parallelogram and the length of all sides?  I am asking in this forum so that I can learn another (i.e. fail-proof) approach to solving...  and just in case I cannot find an answer in the fusion 360 forum.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You are asking for the angle of the oblique line through point $A$ in the figure below (which is not to scale)
such that a parallel line $9$ inches from the line through $A$ passes through $C.$

[image]

To make the solution a bit more general, let $w$ be the width of your piece of wood, so that in your particular question $w = 9.$
Let the coordinates of $C$ be $(a,b),$ that is, the width and height of the rectangle are $a$ and $b.$

Extend the oblique side of the parallelogram from $A$ to the point $E$ such that $\angle AEC$ is a right angle. Then the distance $\lvert CE\rvert = w$ is the width of your piece of wood.
We then have
\begin{align}
\lvert AC\rvert &= \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}, \\
\angle CAD &= \angle ACB = \arctan \frac ab,\\
\angle CAE &= \arcsin \frac {\lvert CE\rvert}{\lvert AC\rvert}
= \arcsin \frac w{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}},\\
\angle DAE &= \angle CAD - \angle CAE. \\
\end{align}